# how to store browse filename in database

Tags: excel, oracle, jsp

I'm creating application where i'm saving excel contain in database,Contain is saving in Database but now i want store upload filename also along with that, i tired with DiskFileItemFactory logic but it wont work anyone can help it's really appreciated here is my excel contain storing code

upload.html

```
<Html>
<HEAD><TITLE>Display file upload form to the user</TITLE></HEAD>

<BODY>
<FORM ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" action="xlsUpload_01.jsp" method="post">
<br><br><br>
<center><table border="2" >
<tr><td><b>Choose the file To Upload:</b>
</td>
<td><INPUT NAME="file" TYPE="file"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">
<p align="right"><INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Upload File" ></p></td></tr>
<table>
</center>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

upload.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem"%>
<%@page import="org.omg.PortableServer.Servant"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory"%>
<%@page import="java.nio.file.Paths"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
     <%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
    <%@page import ="java.util.Date" %>  
    <%@page import ="java.io.*" %>  
    <%@page import ="java.io.FileNotFoundException" %>  
    <%@page import ="java.io.IOException" %>  
    <%@page import ="java.util.Iterator" %>  
    <%@page import ="java.util.ArrayList" %> 
    <%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*" %>
    <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell" %>  
    <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow" %>  
    <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet" %>  
    <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook" %>  
    <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem" %>
    <%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell" %>
    <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row"%>
    <%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet" %>
    <%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook" %>
    <%@page import="com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest" %>
    <%@page import="org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*"%>
    <%@page import="org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook"%>
    <%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload"%>


     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
  <%

    try
    {
 ArrayList CellArrayListHolder=new ArrayList();
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.18.114.213:1831:godb","xe","se");
      String contentType = request.getContentType();
if ((contentType != null) && (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) {
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
int byteRead = 0;
int totalBytesRead = 0;
while (totalBytesRead < formDataLength) {
byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead,formDataLength);
totalBytesRead += byteRead;
}
String file = new String(dataBytes);
String saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1,saveFile.indexOf("\""));
out.println(saveFile);
int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1,contentType.length());
int pos;
pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);
fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
fileOut.flush();
fileOut.close();

%>
<%

PreparedStatement psmnt = null;
FileInputStream fis;
File file1 = new File(saveFile);
FileInputStream file_inut=new FileInputStream(file1);
XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(file_inut);
Sheet firstsheet=workbook.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator<Row> iterator=firstsheet.iterator();
int count=0;
while(iterator.hasNext())
{
   XSSFRow nextrow=(XSSFRow)iterator.next();
    ArrayList rowarraylist=new ArrayList();
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator=nextrow.cellIterator();

    while(cellIterator.hasNext())
    {
        XSSFCell cell=(XSSFCell)cellIterator.next();
        rowarraylist.add(cell);
    }
    CellArrayListHolder.add(rowarraylist);
}
       out.println(CellArrayListHolder);
       ArrayList rowarraylist=null;
       PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement("insert into DYNAMIC_INSERT values(?)");

for(int i=1;i<CellArrayListHolder.size();i++)
{
    rowarraylist=(ArrayList)CellArrayListHolder.get(i);
     //st.setString(1, file_name);
    st.setString(1, rowarraylist.get(0).toString());
    //st.executeUpdate();
    count=st.executeUpdate();

}
if(count>0)
{
       out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
   out.println("alert('File added');");
      out.println("location='xlsUpload.html';");
   out.println("</script>");    
}
}
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
 out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
   out.println("alert('File not found');");
      out.println("location='xlsUpload.html';");
   out.println("</script>");    

}


  %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why don't you just use a servlet for your uploading logic?? Like you're not even doing any html the jsp, so seems quite pointless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my code only i got solution

```
String saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1,saveFile.indexOf("\""));
out.println(saveFile);
```

and this String i set into prepared statement

```
 st.setString(1, saveFile);
```

and i got result what i want exactly

**File_name:hello.xlsx, Description:hello_world_025**