# How to handle blank value in excel while upload in database also want download table in excel without specifying column name in jsp

Tags: excel, oracle, jsp, apache-poi

Actually I have two doubts:

1. I try to upload Excel file in Oracle database, it is uploading correctly but when any blank value coming in it's giving me error. I want when in Excel blank value come, it should be inserted as Null in database, I highlighted which changes done

But now i getting **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7 error**

```
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemStream"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.List"%>
    <%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem"%>
    <%@page import="org.omg.PortableServer.Servant"%>
    <%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory"%>
    <%@page import="java.nio.file.Paths"%>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
            pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
         <%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
        <%@page import ="java.util.Date" %>  
        <%@page import ="java.io.*" %>  
        <%@page import ="java.io.FileNotFoundException" %>  
        <%@page import ="java.io.IOException" %>  
        <%@page import ="java.util.Iterator" %>  
        <%@page import ="java.util.ArrayList" %> 
        <%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*" %>
        <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell" %>  
        <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow" %>  
        <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet" %>  
        <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook" %>  
        <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem" %>
        <%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell" %>
        <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row"%>
        <%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet" %>
        <%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook" %>
        <%@page import="com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest" %>
        <%@page import="org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*"%>
        <%@page import="org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook"%>
        <%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory"%>
    <%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload"%>


         <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
            <style>
                .blueText {
       color: blue;
    }
            </style>

        </head>
        <body>


      <%


    //  try
    //  {
       //try
        //{
     ArrayList CellArrayListHolder=new ArrayList();
     Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.18.114.213:1921:godb","xe","se");
          String contentType = request.getContentType();

    if ((contentType != null) && (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0))
    {
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
    int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
    byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
    int byteRead = 0;
    int totalBytesRead = 0;
    while (totalBytesRead < formDataLength) {
    byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead,formDataLength);
    totalBytesRead += byteRead;
    }
    String file = new String(dataBytes);
    String saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
    saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
    saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1,saveFile.indexOf("\""));
    //out.println(saveFile);
    int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
    String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1,contentType.length());
    int pos;
    pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
    pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
    pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
    pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
    int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
    int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
    int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);


    fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
    fileOut.flush();
    fileOut.close();




    %>

    <%




    //PreparedStatement psmnt = null;
    //FileInputStream fis;
    //try {
    //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    //connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "root");

    File file1 = new File(saveFile);
    FileInputStream file_inut=new FileInputStream(file1);

    if(saveFile.indexOf(".")>0)
    {
     saveFile=saveFile.substring(0,saveFile.lastIndexOf("."));
    }
        String query="Select File_name,to_char(FILE_UPLOAD_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') from DYNAMIC_INSERT where File_name='"+saveFile+"'";
        Statement st1=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st1.executeQuery(query);
        if(rs.next())
        {
              String file_name=rs.getString(1);
              String FILE_UPLOAD_DATE=rs.getString(2);


                           out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
     out.println("alert('File name " + file_name + " already exists File upload Date is "+FILE_UPLOAD_DATE+"')");
     out.println("location='xlsUpload.html';");
       out.println("</script>");


        }
      else
        { 

    XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(file_inut);
    Sheet firstsheet=workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    //Iterator<Row> iterator=firstsheet.iterator();
    Iterator<Row> iterator=firstsheet.rowIterator();
    int count=0;
    int search_id=0;   
     XSSFCell cell;
    String set_null=null;
    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
       XSSFRow nextrow=(XSSFRow)iterator.next();


        ArrayList rowarraylist=new ArrayList();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator=nextrow.cellIterator();

        while(cellIterator.hasNext())
        {


            cell=(XSSFCell)cellIterator.next();
    //added this new line but now i getting 
    **if(cell==null && cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK){
         cell.setCellValue("Null");
     }**

               rowarraylist.add(cell);


        }
        CellArrayListHolder.add(rowarraylist);
    }
           //out.println(CellArrayListHolder);
           ArrayList rowarraylist=null;
           //PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement("insert into DYNAMIC_INSERT values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
           PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into DYNAMIC_INSERT values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

          ps.setString(1, saveFile);
          ps.setInt(2, search_id);
            ps.setDate(3,new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

   **for(int i=0;i<CellArrayListHolder.size()-1;i++)**// change this loop also
    {
        rowarraylist=(ArrayList)CellArrayListHolder.get(i);
         //st.setString(1, file_name);
        ps.setString(4, (rowarraylist.get(0)).toString());
       ps.setString(5, (rowarraylist.get(1)).toString());
       ps.setString(6, (rowarraylist.get(2)).toString());
        ps.setString(7, (rowarraylist.get(3)).toString());
        ps.setString(8, (rowarraylist.get(4)).toString());
        ps.setString(9, (rowarraylist.get(5)).toString());
        ps.setString(10, (rowarraylist.get(6)).toString());
        ps.setString(11, (rowarraylist.get(7)).toString());
        //ps.setString(10, (rowarraylist.get(6)).toString());
        /*st.setString(6, rowarraylist.get(2).toString());
       st.setString(7, rowarraylist.get(3).toString());
       st.setString(8, rowarraylist.get(4).toString());
        st.setString(9, rowarraylist.get(5).toString());
       st.setString(10, rowarraylist.get(6).toString());
      st.setString(11, rowarraylist.get(7).toString());*/
        //st.executeUpdate();
        count=ps.executeUpdate();
    }



    if(count>0)
    {
           out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
       out.println("alert('File uploaded successfully');");
          out.println("location='xlsUpload.html';");
       out.println("</script>");    
    }
        }
    }

      %>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I've never really used an Oracle DB but I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you're not the first person to import an Excel file (that contains blank cells) into Oracle. This isn't a programming question, this is an *"How should I Google This?*" question.  Honestly not trying to be rude, but this site gets 6000+ questions a day - many of which have already been answered here or elsewhere, so you need to make a decent attempt to solve it yourself, and once you do [edit] your question, add your code, and an explanation of your *specific* problem. See "[mcve]" & "[ask] & "[help/on-topic]"

Comment: @ashleedawg : dear sir i'm new here and second thing i was tried from my side but still unable t handle null hence i asked here, and before posting anything i'm doing RnD if i unable to get then only ask here and i treid my self if i got answer im sharing also see example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601545/how-to-store-browse-filename-in-database?noredirect=1#comment88215437_50601545

Answer (score 0):

dear @ashleedawg Here I found my solution my own way  hope helpful for someone

handle null value

```
 <%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemStream"%>
   <%@page import="java.util.List"%>
   <%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem"%>
   <%@page import="org.omg.PortableServer.Servant"%>
   <%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory"%>
   <%@page import="java.nio.file.Paths"%>
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
           pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
        <%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
       <%@page import ="java.util.Date" %>  
       <%@page import ="java.io.*" %>  
       <%@page import ="java.io.FileNotFoundException" %>  
       <%@page import ="java.io.IOException" %>  
       <%@page import ="java.util.Iterator" %>  
       <%@page import ="java.util.ArrayList" %> 
       <%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*" %>
       <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell" %>  
       <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow" %>  
       <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet" %>  
       <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook" %>  
       <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem" %>
       <%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell" %>
       <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row"%>
       <%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet" %>
       <%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook" %>
       <%@page import="com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest" %>
       <%@page import="org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*"%>
       <%@page import="org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook"%>
       <%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory"%>
   <%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload"%>


     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <style>
            .blueText {
   color: blue;
}
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <%!
       public static boolean isRowEmpty(Row row){
         int firstCol = row.getFirstCellNum();
         for(int cnt = 0; cnt<4 ; cnt++){
             Cell cell = row.getCell(firstCol+cnt);
             if(cell!=null && cell.getCellType()!=Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK){
                 return false;
             }
         }
         return true;
    }



        %>   
  <%


//  try
//  {
   //try
    //{
 ArrayList CellArrayListHolder=new ArrayList();
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.18.114.213:1721:godb","xe","se");
      String contentType = request.getContentType();

if ((contentType != null) && (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0))
{
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
int byteRead = 0;
int totalBytesRead = 0;
while (totalBytesRead < formDataLength) {
byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead,formDataLength);
totalBytesRead += byteRead;
}
String file = new String(dataBytes);
String saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1,saveFile.indexOf("\""));
//out.println(saveFile);
int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1,contentType.length());
int pos;
pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);
//out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
// out.println("alert('You are successfully Login at:" + saveFile + "')");
// out.println("location='EmployeeLogin.html';");
//   out.println("</script>");

fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
fileOut.flush();
fileOut.close();




%>

<%




//PreparedStatement psmnt = null;
//FileInputStream fis;
//try {
//Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
//connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "root");

File file1 = new File(saveFile);
FileInputStream file_inut=new FileInputStream(file1);

if(saveFile.indexOf(".")>0)
{
 saveFile=saveFile.substring(0,saveFile.lastIndexOf("."));
}
    String query="Select File_name,to_char(FILE_UPLOAD_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') from DYNAMIC_INSERT where File_name='"+saveFile+"'";
    Statement st1=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=st1.executeQuery(query);
    if(rs.next())
    {
          String file_name=rs.getString(1);
          String FILE_UPLOAD_DATE=rs.getString(2);


                       out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
 out.println("alert('File name " + file_name + " already exists File upload Date is "+FILE_UPLOAD_DATE+"')");
 out.println("location='xlsUpload.html';");
   out.println("</script>");


    }
  else
    { 


XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(file_inut);
XSSFSheet  firstsheet=workbook.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator<Row> iterator=firstsheet.rowIterator();
int count=0;
int search_id=0; 
XSSFRow nextrow;
Row row;

//nextrow=firstsheet.createRow((short)1);
//nextrow.createCell(0).setCellValue("Null");
// nextrow.createCell(1);


StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();

while(iterator.hasNext())
{
 row =(XSSFRow)iterator.next();

**for(int col=0;col<row.getLastCellNum();col++)
 {
     Cell cell=row.getCell(col, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);

 }**// add this line


    ArrayList rowarraylist=new ArrayList();
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator=row.cellIterator();

    while(cellIterator.hasNext())
    {

       XSSFCell cell=(XSSFCell)cellIterator.next();

        rowarraylist.add(cell);





    }

    CellArrayListHolder.add(rowarraylist);

}
       //out.println(CellArrayListHolder);
       ArrayList rowarraylist=null;
       //PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement("insert into DYNAMIC_INSERT values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
       PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into DYNAMIC_INSERT values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

      ps.setString(1, saveFile);
      ps.setInt(2, search_id);
        ps.setDate(3,new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

for(int i=1;i<CellArrayListHolder.size();i++)
{
    rowarraylist=(ArrayList)CellArrayListHolder.get(i);


     //st.setString(1, file_name);
    ps.setString(4, (rowarraylist.get(0)).toString());
   ps.setString(5, (rowarraylist.get(1)).toString());
   ps.setString(6, (rowarraylist.get(2)).toString());
    ps.setString(7, (rowarraylist.get(3)).toString());
    ps.setString(8, (rowarraylist.get(4)).toString());
    ps.setString(9, (rowarraylist.get(5)).toString());
    ps.setString(10, (rowarraylist.get(6)).toString());
    ps.setString(11, (rowarraylist.get(7)).toString());
    //ps.setString(10, (rowarraylist.get(6)).toString());
    /*st.setString(6, rowarraylist.get(2).toString());
   st.setString(7, rowarraylist.get(3).toString());
   st.setString(8, rowarraylist.get(4).toString());
    st.setString(9, rowarraylist.get(5).toString());
   st.setString(10, rowarraylist.get(6).toString());
  st.setString(11, rowarraylist.get(7).toString());*/
    //st.executeUpdate();
    count=ps.executeUpdate();
}



if(count>0)
{
       out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
   out.println("alert('File uploaded successfully');");
      out.println("location='xlsUpload.html';");
   out.println("</script>");    
}
    }
}


  %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Search excel file:
.html

```
<form action="Retrieve_data.jsp" method="post">
        <center>
            <table border="2" >
            <tr><center><td colspan="2"><p align="center"><B>DOWNLOAD THE FILE</B><center></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Enter File Name</b>
</td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtfilename"><br></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">
        <p align="center"><br><input type="submit" value="Download Excel" name="btnsubmit"></p></td></tr>
            </table>
    </form>
```

Retrieve.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="Download_excel.jsp">
<!--          <p align="right"><br><input type="submit" value="Download Excel" name="btnsubmit"></p></td></tr>-->
          <table border="1">
              <tr>
                  <td>FILE_NAME</td>
                  <td>FILE_UPLOAD_DATE</td>
                  <td>POLICY_NO</td>
                  <td> ENDORSEMENT_NO</td>
                  <td> GP_EBAO</td>
                  <td> TOL_PRM</td>
                  <td> PRODUCT_NAME</td>
                  <td> POLICY_NUMBER</td>
                  <td> GP_OF</td>
                  <td>DIFF</td>

              </tr>
              <%


                  String txtfilename=request.getParameter("txtfilename");
                  String btnsubmit=request.getParameter("btnsubmit");
                     if(txtfilename==null ||txtfilename.trim().isEmpty())
       {
           out.println("<html><body><script type=\"text/javascript\">"); 
            out.println("confirm('first name field cannot be blank');"); 
            out.println("location='xlsUpload.html';");
            out.println("</script></body></html>"); 

       }
                     else
                          if(btnsubmit!=null)
                          {

                               response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+txtfilename+".xls");
              Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.18.114.213:1721:godb","xe","se");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from DYNAMIC_INSERT where file_name='"+txtfilename+"'");

        while(rs.next())
        {


              %>
              <tr>

                  <td><%=rs.getString("FILE_NAME")%></td>


              <td><%=rs.getString("FILE_UPLOAD_DATE")%></td>

                  <td><%=rs.getString("POLICY_NO")%></td>

                  <td><%=rs.getString("ENDORSEMENT_NO")%></td>

                  <td><%=rs.getString("GP_EBAO")%></td>

                  <td><%=rs.getString("TOL_PRM")%></td>

                  <td><%=rs.getString("PRODUCT_NAME")%></td>

                  <td><%=rs.getString("POLICY_NUMBER")%></td>
                         <td><%=rs.getString("GP_OF")%></td>
                         <td><%=rs.getString("DIFF")%></td>
              </tr>

              <%
              }
}
              %>
          </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Download.jsp:

```
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemStream"%>
   <%@page import="java.util.List"%>
   <%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem"%>
   <%@page import="org.omg.PortableServer.Servant"%>
   <%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory"%>
   <%@page import="java.nio.file.Paths"%>
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
           pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
        <%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
       <%@page import ="java.util.Date" %>  
       <%@page import ="java.io.*" %>  
       <%@page import ="java.io.FileNotFoundException" %>  
       <%@page import ="java.io.IOException" %>  
       <%@page import ="java.util.Iterator" %>  
       <%@page import ="java.util.ArrayList" %> 
       <%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*" %>
       <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell" %>  
       <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow" %>  
       <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet" %>  
       <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook" %>  
       <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem" %>
       <%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell" %>
       <%@page import ="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row"%>
       <%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet" %>
       <%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook" %>
       <%@page import="com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest" %>
       <%@page import="org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*"%>
       <%@page import="org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook"%>
       <%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory"%>
   <%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            String btnsubmit=request.getParameter("btnsubmit");
            if(btnsubmit!=null)
            {

            String FILE_NAME[]=request.getParameterValues("FILE_NAME");
               String  FILE_UPLOAD_DATE []=request.getParameterValues("FILE_UPLOAD_DATE");
                 String POLICY_NO []=request.getParameterValues("POLICY_NO");
                   String ENDORSEMENT_NO[]=request.getParameterValues("ENDORSEMENT_NO");
                   String GP_EBAO []=request.getParameterValues("GP_EBAO");
                  String TOL_PRM[]=request.getParameterValues("TOL_PRM");
                  String PRODUCT_NAME []=request.getParameterValues("PRODUCT_NAME");
                  String POLICY_NUMBER[]=request.getParameterValues("POLICY_NUMBER");
                  String GP_OF []=request.getParameterValues("GP_OF");
                 String DIFF[]=request.getParameterValues("DIFF");


             Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.18.114.213:1821:godb","sbigi_gtrg","Spacess");

//String query="Select File_name from DYNAMIC_INSERT where File_name='"+FILE_NAME+"'";
//    Statement st1=con.createStatement();
//    ResultSet rs=st1.executeQuery(query);
//    if(rs.next())
//    {

          //String file_name1=rs.getString(1);
          //String file_store="D:\\file_download\\"+FILE_NAME+".xls";

          String file_store="D:\\GODBFILES\\File_upload\\File.xls";
          XSSFWorkbook xwb=new XSSFWorkbook();
          XSSFSheet sheet=xwb.createSheet(file_store+".xls");
         // String file_store=sheet;
          XSSFRow rowhead=sheet.createRow((short)0);
          rowhead.createCell((short)0).setCellValue("FILE_NAME");
          rowhead.createCell((short)1).setCellValue("FILE_UPLOAD_DATE");
          rowhead.createCell((short)2).setCellValue("POLICY_NO");
          rowhead.createCell((short)3).setCellValue("ENDORSEMENT_NO");
          rowhead.createCell((short)4).setCellValue("GP_EBAO");
          rowhead.createCell((short)5).setCellValue("TOL_PRM");
          rowhead.createCell((short)6).setCellValue("PRODUCT_NAME");
          rowhead.createCell((short)7).setCellValue("POLICY_NUMBER");
           rowhead.createCell((short)8).setCellValue("GP_OF");
          rowhead.createCell((short)9).setCellValue("DIFF");

         for(int i=0;i<FILE_NAME.length;i++)
         {
             int j=i+1;
         XSSFRow row=sheet.createRow((short)j);
      row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(FILE_NAME[i]);
      row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(FILE_UPLOAD_DATE[i]);
      row.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(POLICY_NO[i]);
      row.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue(ENDORSEMENT_NO[i]);
      row.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue(GP_EBAO[i]);
      row.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue(TOL_PRM[i]);
      row.createCell((short) 6).setCellValue(PRODUCT_NAME[i]);
      row.createCell((short) 7).setCellValue(POLICY_NUMBER[i]);
      row.createCell((short) 8).setCellValue(GP_OF[i]);
      row.createCell((short) 9).setCellValue(DIFF[i]);




          }
         FileOutputStream fileout=new FileOutputStream(file_store);
         xwb.write(fileout);

            out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
   out.println("alert('File download successfully');");
      out.println("location='xlsUpload.html';");
   out.println("</script>");    


   // }
            }


        %>
    </body>
</html>
```